# ios scrolling background

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I want to make an infintite scrolling background in xcode but when i use this code:

```
    if (self.myAnimatedView.center.y < (self.view.bounds.size.height/4)) {

    float difference = (self.view.bounds.size.height/4) - myAnimatedView.center.y;
    score += (int)difference;
    NSString *nssScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", score];
    scorelabel.text = nssScore;
    myAnimatedView.center = CGPointMake(myAnimatedView.center.x, myAnimatedView.center.y - difference);
    scorelabel.center = CGPointMake(scorelabel.center.x, scorelabel.center.y - difference);



    b1.center = CGPointMake(b1.center.x, b1.center.y - (difference/2));
    b2.center = CGPointMake(b2.center.x, b2.center.y - (difference/2));

    if (b1.center.y > self.view.bounds.size.height - (b1.bounds.size.height/2)) {
        b1.center = CGPointMake(b1.center.x, b2.center.y - 460);
    }

    if (b2.center.y > self.view.bounds.size.height - (b2.bounds.size.height/2)) {
        b2.center = CGPointMake(b2.center.x, b1.center.y - 460);
    }

    float viewWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width;
    float fViewWidthMinusPlatformWidth = viewWidth - 55.0f;
    int iViewWidthMinusPlatformWidth = (int)fViewWidthMinusPlatformWidth;

}
```

This is supposed to make it so when a uiimageview passes th 3/4th mark on the screen, the new background starts being shown. However, it doesnt change the background. Anybody know what isnt working here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you have access to the WWDC2011 videos, I recommend watching the #104 which entirely covers this topic

Comment: Apple has sample code too - InfiniteScrollingView - which does this exactly!